# decrypt a password after authenticate rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am in a situation where after authentication i have to Decrypt the password to the normal text form.

I am using `Digest::MD5.hexdigest` for encryption of password.

Help me out.

Comment: Password should not be stored such that they can be recovered, that is why a hash is used, that is a major security issue. Further storing password hashes is not secure, at a minimum they should use a function that adds a salt such as an HMAC with a random salt, even that is weak, consider using a function such as bcrypt or PBKDF2 that include a work factor. Add what you are trying to accomplish to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The fun answer would be "Rainbow Tables". But that does not help you.

The stricts answer is: you are not supposed to. MD5 is a hashing function, hashing functions are supposed to be one way: you put a string into it and get a hash quite easily, but the other way around is way harder.

So, what you are trying to do is fundamentally wrong. If you want to be able to decrypt your data you should not be using a hashing function, but an actual cryptographic function. But it is not good practice to decrypt your passwords ever, period. So, for us to actually help you, I think you should ask a different question, the one that made you come up with "I need to decrypt the password". Because that answer is most likely wrong.

See also: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html. It describes one way functions a bit better.

Comment: That is a good start but just hashing with a salt does not provide enough security given the speed of today's computation. The hash also needs to be iterated enough time such that the total time is about 100ms. The point s to slow down an attacker enough that it is infeasible to brute-force the hashes.